# Background color of ListView Item not changing

Tags: java, android, listview

After reading through about 20-30 of these questions, I am still struggling with this problem, hope someone can see the problem in the code. I am trying to change the background color of the first item in the listview. The listview displays correctly, but the background color doesn't change:

```
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    arrayList.add(0,"Test");
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
    listView.getAdapter().getView(0, view, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to use `setBackgroundResource()` instead of `setBackgroundColor()`

Comment: check what happens if you do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() right after arrayList.add(0, "Test"); then change the list view item color

Comment: Thanks @mobilepotato7, but unfortunately no cigar

Comment: Thanks @mahmoudmoustafa ! Still doesn't seem to work sadly :(

Comment: try to change background in getView() method in adapter